# Результат n отображений

Tags: python, sympy

Как с помощью sympy можно получить выражение применения функции n раз?

```
x = Symbol('x')
f = x + 1/40 + sin(4*pi*x)/20
h = lambdify(x,f,'numpy')
g = h(f)
print(g)
```

Этот код не работает, потому что сейчас я подставляю символ в функцию, чего делать нельзя. А как можно получить функцию, описывающую результат применения отображения n раз?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy 
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify, pi, sin


x = Symbol('x')
f = x + 1/40 + sin(4*pi*x)/20

n = input("Enter n")

i = int(0)
n = int(n)
expr = x + 1/40 + sin(4*pi*x)/20
for i in range(n-1):
    f = expr + 1/40 + sin(4*pi*(expr))/20
    expr = f
print(f)
```